# SIMBL plugin fails to load framework

Tags: macos, dlopen, simbl

On console, I am getting these errors:

```
27.08.11 20:56:06,371 sandboxd: ([83008]) TextEdit(83008) deny file-read-data /Users/az/Library/Frameworks/FScript.framework/Versions/A/FScript
27.08.11 20:56:06,372 TextEdit: Error loading /Users/az/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/FScriptAnywhere.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FScriptAnywhere:  dlopen(/Users/az/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/FScriptAnywhere.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FScriptAnywhere, 265): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/FScript.framework/Versions/A/FScript
  Referenced from: /Users/az/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/FScriptAnywhere.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FScriptAnywhere
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/az/Library/Frameworks/FScript.framework/Versions/A/FScript: open() failed with errno=1
```

The file `FScriptAnywhere.bundle/Contents/Frameworks/FScript.framework/Versions/A/FScript` exists. Thus, I don't understand the error / the problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

`@executable_path` is relative to the app, not the bundle, i.e. in this case TextEdit. Of course it doesn't find the framework there.

It also cannot load the framework from `~/Library/Frameworks` because of the sandboxing of TextEdit.

Copying the framework over to `/Library/Frameworks` solved the problem.